# I can't align this Image View in center of container - iOS

Tags: ios, swift

See the image below

[image]

I really need align this view in the center of the container.. (StackView) !!

To align the StackView a use Constraints Top 20 right and left 10 only it..
And I'm trying to align this image view at the center of the container but I don't know how I can do it.

Comment: You do not align things inside a stack view. The whole purpose the stack view is that it does the aligning for you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please learn what makes a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask While I understand that you are a beginner, it will help your skills to learn how to search (Google is a very good place to start) about how to use a `UIStackView` and if you have a *specific* issue, ask it. As it is, your question makes it hard to help us not just help you - but help others. It's rather vague about the details of what you've tried. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the left constraint , drag from the stackView to the superView and select center Horizontally from the popup and click **AddConstraints**

**Or**

click the left constraint and edit it to centerX , then set constant = 0

[image]

Comment: sorry.. I'm really a beginner I don't understand what you said.

Comment: in my xcode not appears this options that appears in yours.

Comment: first click the stackView , the constraints will show , then click the left line ( which is the left constraint ) and you will see the right view as in picture , then click the blue arrow of firstItem and edit it , same for second , then set constant to zero

Answer (score 0):

If in attribute inspector, you put alignment for Stackview to "center", it should be in the center. Also, give the image width and hight.